# Unable to create a java client to WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0 using AuthenticationAdmin API Authentication

Tags: java, ldap, client, openldap, wso2-identity-server

I want to create a java client (on eclipse) to connect to WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0 using the API to autenticate, create, save and manage users.

So my idea to configurate the identity server as ldap and to test it with an example of client in java that can authenticate and manage users with API...

I tried to use the example in https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Managing+Users+and+Roles+with+APIs, but i think that the new version of server do not support this example.

Comment: What is the error you get when trying the sample described in the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

apparently you are mixing several things (and the WSO2 documentation is misleading in that point too):

> I want to create a java client (on eclipse) to connect to WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0 using the API to autenticate, create, save and manage users

The web page you refer provides 2 ways to call the admin services:

1. admin web services - you may create or [generate a web service client](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients.html)  and use the web service to connect to the WSO2 IS remotely. How to get the WSDL files is described [in this post](http://madhukaudantha.blogspot.be/2013/02/list-all-web-services-in-wso2.html). That should work with all (even older) versions of the WSO2 IS. I would suggest to use this approach.
2. The code snippet you have provided should works (I haven't try it myself though). I use the default admin web services.

**If you are unable to create a client or connect, you should provide more details where / with what you have the problem.**

> So my idea to configurate the identity server as ldap...

WS2 Identity Server is not an LDAP server. It may have an LDAP configured as a user store (it has an embedded OpenLDAP instance by default). But you can use the web services or the OAuth2 endpoint to authenticate users against configured user stores.

Comment: thanks for ur reply. Can you please show me an example of the configuration as ldap server and an example of using the server to authenticate user using ldap protocol??

Comment: As I mentioned, the WSO2 IS itself is NOT an LDAP server. You can authenticate the users using the OAuth2 or SAML2 protocol. Example: http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/02/securing-your-web-service-with-oauth2-using-wso2-identity-server-1/  For connecting to LDAP directly search this forum, there's already enough posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089848/what-is-best-java-api-to-connect-to-ldap-server)